VB.NET/C# best way to upload list of files to server?
We have a page uploads.aspx with a multi-line text box labeled “Files To Upload” and a button labeled “Upload”.
In the text box the following could be pasted, for example:
/pages/contact-us.aspx
/pages/contact-us.aspx.vb 
/App_Code/Contact/contact.vb
/pages/css/contact.css
/pages/css/contact2.css

What’s the best way these days to upload with VB.NET/C#? FTP? Http?
I have seen a number of code samples but many are deprecated and others are subsequently not recommended.
For example:
Upload file to FTP site using VB.NET
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated
https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0

Are you wanting to upload the files themselves, or just the file names/paths?

Uploading is from a local drive to the server, so the file path should be a complete local path. As for how to do it, There are lots of approaches. I would recommend using (buying) a client-side library (why re-invent a worse wheel?). Then it depends on where you want to put the files and what you plan to do with them, Much of what you need server-side is covered here. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

@JoelCoehoorn Files.

@StevePy Thanks Steve. It’s not core but rather normal ASP.NET. We were hoping to do something more simple and not rely on 3rd party libraries.

The issue of course is that you can't use a asp.net webpage to simply upload any old file under YOUR code control. This is simply not allowed, and if a web page code could "choose" what files to upload, then when you come to my site to view my cat pictures? Then my web browser would start rummaging on your hard drive, stealing some file called "my banking", or some Excel sheet called "my passwords", or I'll even steal your Outlook files.
So, on a web page, file names pasted into a text box is simply not allowed, nor permitted by ANY browser. If such an approach was allowed, then no one would EVER risk using the internet or visiting any web site.
In fact, with a web page, the web server can NEVER even know what file paths are being used for the file. Again, the browser is sandboxed this way for reasons of security. And of course, you might be up-loading files using an iPad or Android phone, of which things like drive letters etc. are completely different then windows.
So, the ONLY permitted way to select files in a browser is though use of the FileUpLoad control.
However, of course the FileUpLoad control is rather lame, makes the browser feel like it is frozen, and no progress bar, or even a cancel button is provided.
However, you can of course allow the user to select files, and then JavaScript + AJAX is then allowed to upload the file(s) in chunks. This approach not only vast reduces memory, but tends to result in file sizes of unlimited length to be uploaded. Since such files are up-loaded in chunks, then memory issues for the server is for the most part also eliminated. And this also vast reduces browser memory.
And while you can't have some cut + paste into a text box, you can like any good upload file utility provide a "hot spot" in which you can drag + drop 1 or even many files at the same time. So, this setup is as good as cut + paste, and in some ways even better.
So, no use trying to roll your own code when a good number of high-quality file upload libraries are available - and many of them are free.
So, I much suggest adopting a well used uploading library that's been maintained over the years and is "battle hardened".
The file uploading utility I use with webforms sites is the AjaxFileUploader that is included with the Ajax Toolkit. This toolkit is open source, and it maintained by the folks at DevExpress.
You can find the AjaxToolkit on GitHub, or even via Nugget inside of Visual Studio.
Here is what the process looks like:
So, the user can select files and then drag + drop into the "hot spot" on the browser.
Hence this:

So, I used drag + drop.
And now hitting upload button, we see this:

So, in summary:
Grab an existing well built uploading utility. They work well, and provide a great UI along with a nice progress bar etc.
They allow a hot spot drag + drop, or standard "select" a file options. Both of which allow multiple files.
I added a radio button + two div areas, one with a GridView, and the other with the AjaxFileUpLoad control dropped into the page.
I'm most happy to post the vb.net + markup for the above sample screens used.

Thanks Albert. That’s an excellent and comprehensive response. The page we wanted to use to upload though only exists on localhost with no plan to ever upload it to a live server.

Well, if the web server is internal, the above approach still is a great web interface and uploading utility. It not 100% clear what you mean by local host, since a web page assumes a correctly setup web server (running IIS) and then your published web site to that server. You tagged this post as asp.net - so that assumes a web server + web application project type. Browsers don't run nor do much without a server, at least when running asp.net applications.

@AlbertDKallal Oh it’s just the local internal server that was installed by Visual Studio.

Well, for development, that can work, but if others on that internal network are going to use the web site, then you want to install IIS on some machine, since the internal web server with VS is not really setup for "other" users to use that site. The internal server that VS uses is now "IIS Express", but for a web server that going to run for other users, then I would install + setup IIS on that computer.
